# IC engine Exhaust gases flow simulation through absorption type muffler

Tags: sound

How is the exhaust gas flow through the absorption type muffler. I am interested to know how the exhaust gases enter the absorption material(fiber glass) before leaving through the end pipe. What makes the exhaust gases to enter the fiber glass for sound silencing and how is the path followed by the exhaust gases through the muffler.

Comment: Each cylinder forces the exhaust gas into the exhaust manifold.

Comment: Thanks Mike. But how does the exhaust gases flow into the absorption material (fiber glass) and not directly to the atmosphere through the perforated pipe?

Comment: "how does the exhaust gases flow" you should check out how an IC engine works - pressure caused by combustion and piston position. As for th perforated pipe you need to provide a diagram of the device you are talking about.

Comment: Where did you read that the "*the exhaust gases to enter the fiber glass for sound silencing*". Please provide a link. Only the sound enters the fibre glass; not the gases, I think. Please provide a diagram for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Fiberglass or some other sound-absorbing material surrounds a straight pipe in an absorption muffler.  These are typically called glass packs in the US.  The straight pipe is perforated, and the sound moves to the surrounding sound-absorbing material (traditionally fiberglass).  There will be minimal gas flow through the surrounding material.

As one might surmise, these mufflers do not reduce sound very much.